# Ionic 6 Capacitor: add permissions to AndroidManifest.xml on build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-manifest, android-permissions

With Ionic Cordova, it was possible to use the config.xml file in the project to add specific permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file during build. That way, when the Android platform folder was removed, the permissions were added to the manifest file each time when rebuilding the app.

Now I am migrating to Capacitor and looking for a similar solution. The Capacitor documentation is however very vague, and mentions direct editing of the AndroidManifest.xml. Now I already ran twice into a situation where I had to remove the Android folder, so the permission edits were lost as well.

Does anyone know how and where to configure the permissions for Ionic Capacitor, so compiling the app will also set the permissions back to the manifest file?

Comment: Did you get any solution yet? since I am finding for the same thing.

Comment: No solution... I guess this must be scripted.

Comment: I have exactly same issue, using DevOps pipelines in order to build/deploy my Ionic 6/Capacitor 3 app to AppCenter... Its very frustrating that there's no Cordova - similar way to take care of this.. Sadly after couple hours of pulling my hair I think I would have to agree that this step need to be scripted in order to modify AndroidManifest file after building the app.. If anyone have any other solution please share.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/trapeze :

Trapeze makes it easy to automate the configuration of native mobile iOS and Android projects, and supports traditional native, Ionic, Capacitor, React Native, Flutter, and .NET MAUI.

Trapeze works by automating the modification of pbxproj, plist, XML, Gradle, JSON, resource, properties, and other files in iOS and Android app projects. It features a configuration-driven tool that takes a YAML file with iOS and Android project modifications and performs those modifications from the command line interactively. A Project API is also available for writing custom JavaScript/TypeScript project modification scripts for full control. The configuration tool uses this API under the hood.

Comment: I think trapeze is the way to solve this problem.  I use it to set all the non-default values in the manifest